# For more than 200 records trigger does not get fire

Tags: apex, trigger

I have created on `after update` and `after insert` trigger on `Opportunity` object. To prevent the trigger from getting called twice ( by workflows) I have set a static variable.

```
    trigger SyncOppty on Opportunity (after insert,after update) {

        if(SyncInfoController.isExecute) {

            SyncInfoController.isExecute=false;
            SyncInfoController.createUpdateSyncInfo(Trigger.new, Trigger.isUpdate);

        }
   }
```

Now the problem is when I am exporting 1100 opportunities the trigger fires only for the first 200 batch records. It does not get fire for the rest of the batch.

It looks like `SyncInfoController.isExecute` is not getting set back to `true` and due to that, the trigger body is not getting fired.

I am a little unsure here how the trigger treats the static variable here. Does it gets automatically reset on each transaction ? if yes then it seems not working in my case and I am not sure how to deal with it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the main issue with using a simple `static boolean` to control recursion. Once set, it'll prevent further chunks from running through your trigger.

Before I continue, a few things of note:

- The treatment of static variables is based on where that variable is defined (not where it's used)
- Static variables declared inside a trigger (as opposed to defined in an Apex class) are basically worthless. They get reset at the start of each new chunk of (up to) 200 records for the trigger.
- Static variables declared inside of an Apex class live for the entire transaction (transaction != trigger chunk)

The next step up in terms of recursion control is to use a static `set<Id>` to store the record Ids you've encountered so far (so you can avoid processing them again)

A brief example

```java
public class MyRecursionControl{
    static Set<Id> encounteredIds = new Set<Id>();
}

---
trigger myTrigger on MyObject(after insert, after update){
    // after insert and after update, we have access to trigger.newMap
    Map<Id, MyObject> recordsToProcess = trigger.newMap;

    // We could loop over trigger.newMap instead (to generate recordsToProcess), but
    //   this is shorter to write (and might be more efficient, maybe)
    // There's a chance this won't work because recordsToProcess is a reference to trigger.newMap
    //   (and I don't think we're allowed to add/remove things from trigger context variables).
    // If this gives you an error, then cloning trigger.newMap should fix that (at the cost of
    //   needing to later apply changes directly to the object instances in trigger.newMap
    //   if we're in a before update trigger and want to take advantage of not needing dml)
    recordsToProcess.keySet().removeAll(MyRecursionControl.encounteredIds);

    // add the records we're going to process to the set of Ids we've encountered so that we
    //   don't process them again
    MyRecursionControl.addAll(recordsToProcess.keySet());

    // continue to do the work you want to do
    // work on recordsToProcess instead of trigger context variables

}
```

Comment: usual caveat that if triggers are executing in a `AllOrNone=false` use case, and some recs fail, some succeed, when SFDC re-executes the trigger on the partial successes, the static variables will NOT be reset and [certain use cases will not perform as expected](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/202097/prevent-duplicates-trigger-workflow-field-update-trigger-w-callout-allorn)

Comment: @cropredy That was a good read. The query cost to the queueable solution would be a big consideration for me. I wonder if the records inside of trigger context variables change on partial failure (wouldn't make much sense to send the failed records through triggers again). Something for me to look at when I have some downtime.

Comment: also- http://cropredysfdc.com/2017/12/16/triggers-workflow-recursion-control-callouts-allornone/ - i ended up w/o using the queueable solution and instead a simple sobject

Comment: @cropredy I appreciate what you had noticed here but in your context, there is a need to compare old with new values. However , my context is a little different where I just need to add reference of oppty object into another custom object. I may use your approach to maintain `Transaction_State__c` in future if required

Answer (score 5):

> I am a little unsure here how the trigger treats the static variable here. Does it gets automatically reset on each transaction ?

Yes, but you only have one transaction here. Each trigger invocation of 200 records is *not* a separate transaction.

This is a perfect example of why most static Boolean patterns for trigger flow control are poisonous. The outcome is exactly what you see here: records beyond 200 are not processed. You may also see a variety of other negative outcomes in different scenarios - for instance, you'll note that your trigger here will only run on one trigger *event* (`after insert`, `after update`) per transaction.

The safe pattern to prevent recursion while performing DML on the same object as the trigger is to reset the Boolean around each DML operation, e.g.

```
    if(SyncInfoController.isExecute) {
        SyncInfoController.isExecute=false;
        SyncInfoController.createUpdateSyncInfo(Trigger.new, Trigger.isUpdate);
        SyncInfoController.isExecute=true;
    }
```

That just means that your trigger won't take action in response to DML events that are part of the trigger's own action.

Comment: I tried this and end up getting two entries for records my 1120 records are no 2240 as both the events `INSERT` and `UPDATE` are getting captured